# I am unable to remove duplicates from my array , just getting the last element of the array

Tags: arrays, perl, unique, duplicates

I know there is a similar question but I took tips from there and applied to my code to remove the duplicates. All I am getting is just the last element of the array. I am unable to see where I am going wrong. please help me find out where a I am going wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;

my $localdir = 'images/p/';
my @filefound;
my @split1;
my $before;

find(sub {push @filefound, $File::Find::name if /.jpg$/ },$localdir);

for(@filefound) { print "$_ \n";}

foreach (@filefound){
my @result = split('_',$_);
@split1 = $result[0];
}

my %unique = ();
foreach my $item (@split1)
{ 
    $unique{$item} ++;
}

my @myuniquearray = keys %unique;
foreach (@myuniquearray){ print "$_  \n";}
```

Comment: `my @myuniquearray = grep { $unique{$_} == 1 } keys %unique`

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html

Comment: I am still getting the last element when I print it !! :(

Comment: Of course you do. In the loop, you overwrite the array every iteration, so of course only the last overwrite is saved. `@split1 = $result[0];` Hence my previous comment about `push`

Comment: Yeah i got that one , thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
foreach (@filefound){
    my @result = split('_',$_);
    @split1 = $result[0];
}
```

You are reassigning `@split1` each time through the loop. Try `push @split1, $result[0];` instead to push the new element onto the existing list.

Answer (score 1):

In the first foreach you are overwriting `@split1` in every iteration instead of adding the result to a list.

Answer (score 1):

> @split1 = $result[0];
>   You get only one element in your array there.